# Wiki edit review uses wrong word when describing previous revisions

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

See the screenshot below

> [image: wiki answered?]

tag wikis are not questions, so they're not *answered* but *created* or *edited*.

Comment: hmmm, tag wikis and excerpts are stored in the posts table, so I suspect this is a function of that. I guess another lookup on posttypeid could be done, as it is for questions and answers, but does it matter _that much_?

Comment: Could just say *posted* I suppose.

Comment: @Ben: A bug's a bug, although you might assign a low priority as it is nowhere near critical. Small inaccuracies are just ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed a few months ago: tag wikis & tag wiki excerpts now display "created", e.g.

> [image]